# Jmeter: Is it possible to use response date of one request in another request?

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

Our Application (iOS) will send image details to the server, server generates image ID and sends it back to the app as a response data, then the app will upload the image thumbnail and the actual image to the server using that image ID.
So here I have to use the response data (Image_ID) of the first request to upload the image.
Please tell me how to simulate this scenario using Jmeter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use regular expression extractor to extract data from response of previous req and then use it in next request.

Comment: read about correlation in jmeter examples.

Comment: I used “Regular Expression Extractor” to do this, But I am getting problem in following scenario:
For Example:
Test Plan:
1. First Request (/v1/images/postimage). 
2. Regular Expression Extractor (Reference name: image_id, Regular Expression: {"image_id”:(.+?)})
3. Upload thumbnail Request (/v1/images/${image_id}/uploadthumb).
4. Upload Image Request (/v1/images/${image_id}/uploadimage).

Here it will take proper value for 3rd (Upload thumbnail Request) request, But it will take default value for the 4th request (Upload Image Request).

Comment: all requests are in same threagroup/transaction controller?. maybe you are victim of variable scoping. try putting all request in a single transaction controller or single threadgroup without any tran. controller. If you need details I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: All requests are under same Thread Group.

Comment: Got it, I had to put Regular Expression Extractor inside First request. (Other wise I think it will run for every requests).              Thanks Nachiket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To  store the whole response data into a JMeter Variable:

1. Add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which generates desired response data (in your case Image ID)
2. Add the following code into Beanshell PostProcessor's script area:

   ```
   vars.put("imageID", new String(data));
   ```

   where `imageID` can be any meaningful variable name of your choice and `data` is a shorthand for parent sampler response data represented as binary byte array.
3. Refer variable value as `${imageID}` or `${__V(imageID)}` where required in the current Thread Group

If you don't need the whole response data but a smaller part you can get required value using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) PostProcessor.

References:

- [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)
- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [jMeter - Regular Expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: I used “Regular Expression Extractor” to do this, But I am getting problem in following scenario:
For Example:
Test Plan:
1. First Request (/v1/images/postimage). 
2. Regular Expression Extractor (Reference name: image_id, Regular Expression: {"image_id”:(.+?)})
3. Upload thumbnail Request (/v1/images/${image_id}/uploadthumb).
4. Upload Image Request (/v1/images/${image_id}/uploadimage).

Here it will take proper value for 3rd (Upload thumbnail Request) request, But it will take default value for the 4th request (Upload Image Request).

Comment: Got it, I had to put Regular Expression Extractor inside First request. (Other wise I think it will run for every requests).              Thanks Dmitri T.